# How make an action run only when the field becomes unselected?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Right now the value of an input text field changes upon the successful match in my code. It looks like this:

```
if(jsonResponse.id != null) {
    document.getElementById('product_id').value = jsonResponse.id;
}
```

The problem is that if, i.e., I have a product with `id=200` and a product with `id=2003`, then when a user wants to search for `2003`, the moment the typed value is 200 - the input field text will change with the corresponding answer for 200, instead of 2003. This is not convenient.

So my goal is to add some additional check (or something like that), that will allow `document.getElementById('product_id').value = jsonResponse.id;` only after the cursor is not anymore in the input text field (when the field is not selected anymore).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run a function when a text field loses focus, you can use jQuery's [`blur`](http://api.jquery.com/blur/) event handler:

```
$('.mytextfield').blur(function(){
    var value = $(this).val();
    // use value
});
```

[jsbin example](http://jsbin.com/OyETeco/1/edit)

Answer (score 0):

You wait for user to press enter, as soon as user press the enter then process the text.

```
document.onkeypress = function(e) {
            e = e || window.event;
            var charCode = (typeof e.which == "number") ? e.which : e.keyCode;
            if (charCode==13) { //ENTER PRESSED
                     /*   your code */
            }
               };
```

Comment: Is it possible to make not with the press of Enter, but just after the field is not selected anymore?

Answer (score 0):

You can do also like this:

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="" onblur="yourFunction();"/>
```

Or by Jquery.